# Will Optimizely work with CardinalPath GAS wrapper?

Tags: google-analytics, optimizely

Looking at whether using Optimizely A/B testing would work with gas.

"Because Optimizely runs first and creates _gaq, it's very important for any custom implementation of GA to make sure it checks for the existence of _gaq before it runs, and if _gaq exists (because Optimizely created it and added a custom variable), make sure to include that value when the custom implementation runs."

Does this in the GAS src have that effect?:

`window['_gaq'] = window['_gaq'] || [];
var _prev_gas = window['_gas'] || [];`

Links

[GAS on Github](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas)

[Optimizely GA troubleshooting page](https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/200068399-Google-Analytics-integration-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - source: maintainer of GAS and used both at my last company

Willing to patch if you find out otherwise. https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas/issues?sort=created&state=open